# How to dynamically order my react components according to the order I get from my request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to transfer the responsibility of the order of my components to be passed to the .JSON file I GET from my request. In the following component, I get a list of 2 components with names `Component1` and `Component2` and their data `component1_data` and `component2_data` accordingly. How can I put my components in the same order that they are on this list?

Also, there is an if-else statement which is pushing the relevant content to the appropriate list. How can I write this more efficient so I will remove the repetition?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Component1 from '../component1';
import Component2 from '../component2';

const Landing = (props) => {

    const component1_data = [];
    const component2_data = [];

    if (data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].component_type === 'component1') {
                const contentElement = data[i];
                component1_data.push({ ...contentElement, content: props.data[contentElement.content] });
            } else if (data[i].component_type === 'component2') {
                const contentElement = data[i];
                component2_data.push({ ...contentElement, content: props.data[contentElement.content] });
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Component1 data={component1_data} />
            <Component2 data={component2_data} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Landing;
```

```
"landing": [
      {
        "component_type": "component2",
        "content": "component2"
      },
      {
        "component_type": "component1",
        "content": "component1"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: the simplest way to do this, is to create a mapping / registry.  which holds a reference to the component definition, of the component you want to create, by key.  in your case you could express this as `var register = { "component1" : div }`  which would give you a div component definition. now if you did `MyDiv = registry["component1"];` - you can use as follows: `<MyDiv></MyDiv>` - but it doesn't have to be a div, it can be an component..  i use this to create user defined dashboards

Comment: so in your case: `var register = { "component1" : Component1 }` and `MyComponent1 = registry["component1"];` then: `<MyComponent1 data={component1_data}></MyComponent1>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic rundown on a better way of doing it: map your data into the components that you want to render. Then you can output that directly in the JSX.

```
import React from 'react';
import Component1 from '../component1';
import Component2 from '../component2';
// This is a mapping between the contentElement strings to the Component you want to render
const componentMap = {
  component1: Component1,
  component2: Component2,
};
const Landing = (props) => {
  const components = data.map((datum) => {
    const ComponentType = componentMap[datum.contentElement];
    if(!ComponentType) return null;
    // This returns the component you want with the data
    // If the props aren't set up how you want, you should be able to modify it to have the right names
    return (
      <ComponentType data={{ ...datum, content: props.data[datum.content] }} />
    );
  });

  return <div>{components}</div>;
};

export default Landing;
```